# ARCore with different scene / real camera

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-emulator, arcore

Friends and me are trying out the ARCore of Google. But since there is only limited phone support at the moment, none of us owns one of the supported phones.

So I googled and found out that you can run ARCore in the Android Emulator, which works nice.
But I have a question regarding that given scene: Can we change it somehow, or use the webcam from our laptops in order to test it under our real scenery?

Ultimately we want to build something with Unity + ARCore, but our current Unity-App crashs when running it on the Emulator. So I want to ask, if this is even possible in the current state, to build an .apk with ARCore in Unity and run in on the Emulator?

Sorry for alot of questions.

Comment: When you run your project in Unity, if you got your webcam plugged to your pc, do not show on your Unity? As far as I know it should.

Comment: @Lotan ARCore is does not require just a webcam, it needs other hardware components to function properly since the tracking is marker-less. So it would not work with Unity's webcam on its own. Unless of course the hardware is emulated to act as a real mobile phone.

Comment: @Hristo Damn, I was deleting the comment right now (I was testing my ARCore project). You're right, it needs the mobile phone deploy.

Comment: @Hristo So testing in Unity is impossible if you have no phone. Is there a way I can test it through the emulator? Because I tried to install it on the emulator and run it, but I get an error "your device does not match the hardware".

The sample ARCore app works though

Comment: @Hristo I don't really know, did you check API compatibility? The other thing could be that the phone that you're emulating maybe is not compatible, check that list: https://forum.unity.com/threads/androids-that-work-with-unity-android.77388/

Comment: @Lotan Hm I will check that list out. Currently I was emulating a Google Pixel 2

Comment: I myself am also looking for a solution to this problem, so I have no implementation yet.

Comment: @Hrist oh I see :/